# How to auto play music as soon as my app starts?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, audio

I need some help with my app I have recently started. I am a very big starter to coding so please do help me, it'll mean a lot. I need a piece of music to play as soon as the user enters my app, i have followed other youtube tutorials but they only work for the older Xcode versions, so please help thank you so much.

Comment: how about puttin your mp3 at appdidfinishlaunching

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about putting it in you `application didFinishLaunching` but be sure to instantiate it in you .h and .m.

Something like this should do your problem:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/YOURMUSICNAME.wav"];
    NSLog(@"Path to play: %@", resourcePath);
    NSError* err;

    //Initialize our player pointing to the path to our resource
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                 [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath] error:&err];

    if( err ){
        //bail!
        NSLog(@"Failed with reason: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
    }
    else{
        //set our delegate and begin playback
        player.delegate = self;
        [player play];
        player.numberOfLoops = -1;
        player.currentTime = 0;
        player.volume = 1.0;
    }
}
```

Then if you want to stop it:

```
[player stop];
```

or pause it :

```
[player pause];
```

and also import it in your header file:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

**EDIT:**

You should to ofcourse declare it in your header, then synthesize it.

//.h and add the **bold** part:

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <**AVAudioPlayerDelegate**> {

```
AVAudioPlayer *player;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

//.m

```
@synthesize player;
```

Comment: where should i declare player? Because right now it comes up with error's saying " Use of undeclared identifier 'player' " thanks and if i declare it do i connect it to anything in the storyboard?

Comment: Check my edited answer, and tell me if you still encounter problem

Comment: thank you for all your help, I have done what you told me and all the error's have disappeared but when I simulate it no music is played, would you like to see the code or something like that?? :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AVAudioPlayer`. It pretty straight forward to use:

```
NSURL *path = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[DataPersister getQualifiedPathForFileInDirectory:DataPersisterPathBundle fileName:@"music.mp3"]];
NSError *outError;

AVAudioPlayer *musicSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:path error:&outError];
[musicSound play];
[path release];
```

Remember to import

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/MUSIC.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
[audioPlayer play];
audioPlayer.volume = 1.0;
audioPlayer.currentTime = 2;
```

Use this at `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method will play music for sure

Happy Coding ;)