# Cant stop AVAudioPlayer from playing

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Here is my code

AppDelegate.m 
I use this code to start AVAudioPlayer. It works fine.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{


    NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/Helloween.mp3"];
    NSLog(@"Path to play: %@", resourcePath);
    NSError* err;

    //Initialize our player pointing to the path to our resource
    backgroundMusic = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
              [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath] error:&err];

    if( err ){
        //bail!
        NSLog(@"Failed with reason: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
    }
    else{
        //set our delegate and begin playback
        backgroundMusic.delegate = self;
        [backgroundMusic play];
        backgroundMusic.numberOfLoops = -1;
        backgroundMusic.currentTime = 0;
       backgroundMusic.volume = 1.0;
    }
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

In AppDelegate.h I add framework and AVAudioPlayer

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    AVAudioPlayer *backgroundMusic;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) AVAudioPlayer *backgroundMusic;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

In ViewController.m i also add framework AVFoundation and import AppDelegate.h

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#define fName @"data.plist"
#define kNames @"data.plist"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize backgroundMusic;
-(IBAction)stopMusic:(id)sender {
   AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
      [appDelegate.backgroundMusic stop];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
      [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    //set the position of the button
    button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 20, 20);
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(stopMusic:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //add the button to the view
    [self.view addSubview:button];
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#define kNames @"data.plist"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>  {
 AVAudioPlayer *backgroundMusic;
}
```

I need stop the AudioPlayer with button.

---

Here is my code

AppDelegate.m 
I use this code to start AVAudioPlayer.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{


    NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/Helloween.mp3"];
    NSLog(@"Path to play: %@", resourcePath);
    NSError* err;

    //Initialize our player pointing to the path to our resource
    backgroundMusic = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
              [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath] error:&err];

    if( err ){
        //bail!
        NSLog(@"Failed with reason: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
    }
    else{
        //set our delegate and begin playback
        backgroundMusic.delegate = self;
        [backgroundMusic play];
        backgroundMusic.numberOfLoops = -1;
        backgroundMusic.currentTime = 0;
       backgroundMusic.volume = 1.0;
    }
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    AVAudioPlayer *backgroundMusic;
}
-(IBAction)stopMus:(id)sender;
@property(nonatomic,retain) AVAudioPlayer *backgroundMusic;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#define fName @"data.plist"
#define kNames @"data.plist"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize backgroundMusic;
-(IBAction)stopMusic:(id)sender {
   AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
      [appDelegate.backgroundMusic stop];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
      [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    //set the position of the button
    button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 20, 20);
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(stopMusic:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //add the button to the view
    [self.view addSubview:button];
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#define kNames @"data.plist"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>  {
 AVAudioPlayer *backgroundMusic;
}
```

I need stop the AudioPlayer with button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add `UIButton` to the `UIView` like this:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

//set the position of the button
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(yourMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

//add the button to the view
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Then,

```
-(IBAction)yourMethod:(id)sender {
 [backgroundMusic stop];


}
```

After your done with the button, you can remove it via `[button removeFromSuperView];`
I think, something like that should work :) Please ask if your having problem with my answer.

Comment: Ok, I add the button, but it don't stop the AudioPlayer, because I wrote the code for AVAudioPlayer in AppDelegate.m

Comment: look at this my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11303496/1302274 it should help you.

Comment: I used - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions method. But I need to stop music with a button in ViewController.m

Comment: add it as a subview, then do what i told you,

Comment: I have done this, but it still not working. Also I try this code 

-(IBAction)stopMusic:(id)sender {
   AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
      [appDelegate.backgroundMusic stop];
    
}
but it is not help me))

Comment: okay, I get how about put your AVAudioPlayer in `viewDidAppear`/`viewDidLoad` instead of `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{'

Comment: I have try that, but there is other problem. When I putting AVAudioPlayer in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear and go to other view, AudioPlayer start play anew. So I hear 2 musics at the same time. And I don't know how to correct it. Thanks for patience.

Comment: in `viewDidDisAppear` put `[backgroundMusic stop];` then in another viewController start your music again.